# I'm having trouble with installing cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I just installed CakePHP 2.2.10 on my local host. I made all the necessary changes in the documentation. I created the database file, changed the security salt and the cipher seed, etc. However When I access the CakePhp folder through WAMP, I'm getting the following message:

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

I did some of the create a blog tutorial from the documentation and when I go to localhost/cakephp2/Posts/ the browser shows: "The requested URL /cakephp2/Posts/ was not found on this server."

Any insight into what I should do? I'm really used to codeIgniter, but I've heard a lot of good things about cake and want try them out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure to enable the rewrite_module in WAMPServer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's most likely because you do not have `mod_rewrite` enabled.
Make sure it's enabled by checking the image below.

[image]

[Source](http://www.tutorialjinni.com/2011/08/wamp-server-localhost-url-rewriting.html)

Comment: Thanks tigrang! It worked! I thought it wasn't at first, because there was no check mark next to rewrite_module after I clicked on it, but after I restarted wamp and clicked on it and restarted again, it started working.

Comment: Hmm, when you make changes wamp usually restarts itself. Anyway, glad you got it working.